# Raspberry PI 4 Solid Red and Green light

Tags: raspbian, eeprom

I just set up my Raspberry Pi with the Pi Imager and everything was working fine, suddenly the power cord was unplugged and I had installed an application, after that now I get the solid red and green lights and green light only blinks about twice or once at start up then stays at green solid, I cannot log into the Raspberry Pi anymore using PuTTY, I tried the Pi Imager misc utility option and selected SD card boot which is supposed to fix the EEPROM, but it did not work, after that option I re-installed the OS a few times to the SD card and nothing seems to work.

Comment: have you tried a different SD card? Or, you should be able to boot from a USB drive - does anything appear on the monitor when you boot?

Comment: you don't install applications by pulling the power cord ... your description is very unclear ... which came first, the power cord unplugging, or the application install?

Comment: I installed the application then after it was installed, the cord got pulled away by accident.

Comment: @JaromandaX Going to try that and get back in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Solid red and irregular green usually indicate power supply issues. Please use the official Raspberry Pi power supply.

Comment: I am using the official power supply and facing this issue :/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem by booting from USB , I used the imager to publish the image to USB.